# InAppBrowser listener throws "Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm doing a login page on Ionic framework and I need to know first if the user exists on my database and second if the user has an accesstoken from webex api, the problem is when the user doesn't have an accesstoken I have to show a webview from webex service and then the user has to make login and I have to catch the code generated by webex and then get the accesstoken via api, after that I have to redirect the user to another page.

I already able to get the accesstoken after the user logged in webex, the problem is when I try to navigate to the success route, I get:

> "Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?"

With this function I get the code from webex url:

```
getWebexAccess( response: any ){
    this.showLoading = false;
    if(response.data.hasOwnProperty("URL")){ 
      let browserRef = this.inAppBrowser.create(response.data.URL, '_blank', 'location=no');
      browserRef.on("loadstop").subscribe((event)=>{
        if ((event.url).indexOf('?code=') !== -1) {
          try{
            let urlCode = event.url.slice(event.url.indexOf('?code=') + '?code='.length);
            let chunkCode = urlCode.split("&");
            let code = chunkCode[0] + '&email=' + this.user.email + '&' + chunkCode[1];
            this.getAccessToken( code );
            browserRef.close();
          }catch( error ){
            console.log( error );
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

After that I call getAccessToken

```
getAccessToken( code: string ){
    this.apiChat.getAccessToken( code ).subscribe( (response: any) => {
      if(response.status === 200){
        this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(["/chat"])).then();
      }
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log( errorResponse );
    });
  }
```

If I leave the code without this.ngZone.run() the console returns the error, but if I leave the code with this.ngZone.run() the console doesn't show the error but the navigation doesn't work either

That is my problem that I'm not able to navigate to the chat page after the login is success. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: At the end I realize that the problem was in my authGuard it was always false until I create a method to change dinamically the value, because I had to do two validations and after that give the right credentials to the user. Thank you for read.

Comment: Could you please post how you got it running?